# Japanese encoding JIS_X_0208 codepage in python and C++

Tags: character-encoding, codepages, cjk

I am trying to encode and decode Japanese characters that are incoded in JIS_X_0208.

In python I use this command to encode my string from uft-8 to japanese characters

```
string.decode('utf8').encode('iso2022_jp')
```

to encode the kanji properly

I decode it in C++ with this line to UTF-16

```
MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, &s[0], s.size(), &unicodeBuffer[0], s.size());
```

All the kanji are properly encoded/decoded.
But the problem is that it is not compliant with JIS_X_0208. I prefer to specify that the usage of JIS_X_0208 is mandatory and I can't change it. 
For instance, the roman character are supposed to be encoded in two bytes with the first one starting with 0x23, for example le letter T should be encoded as 0x23 0x54 (according to both he JIS_X_0208 wikipedia page and the sample I was gevin as example).

I guess the only issue I have is to find the correct codepage for the encoding, but I can't find the one I need.

Does anyone know what the correct codepage is, or at least where I can find the available codepage for C++ and python on Windows?

Thank you in advance.